What am I doing wrong in this section of VBA code?
My VBA experience is from using/analyzing the recorder and googling, so that's why you might see something ridiculous in my code. This macro worked for several years, but I added this section of code recently and Excel now crashes most every time I run it - crashes meaning all windows force shut and I have to open a new instance of Excel, which then shows me my recovered files. I notice that it will generally run okay after the crash (when Excel opens a new, clean instance) which makes me think there's some cache or data that's clogging things up, but sometimes it even crashes with a new instance. Any input or ideas? Thank you
======================================
Range(LColNumberEditLetter & "1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Local BU"

Sheets("Start Here").Select

'FIND
    Dim ColStartHereInput As Long
    
    ColStartHereInput = Cells.Find(What:="Input", _
                        After:=Range("A1"), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        
    'Convert Cell Number to Column Letters
    Dim ColStartHereInputLetter
        ColStartHereInputLetter = Split(Cells(1, ColStartHereInput).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
        
'FIND
    Dim ColStartHereVariable As Long
    
    ColStartHereVariable = Cells.Find(What:="Variable", _
                        After:=Range("A1"), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        
    'Convert Cell Number to Column Letters
    Dim ColStartHereVariableLetter
        ColStartHereVariableLetter = Split(Cells(1, ColStartHereVariable).Address(True, False), "$")(0)

Sheets(Roster).Select

Range(LColNumberEditLetter & "2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC" & ColLocationDescrEdit & ",'Start Here'!C" & ColStartHereInput & ":C" & ColStartHereVariable & ",2,FALSE),""Manually Review - New Office"")"
Range(LColNumberEditLetter & "2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(LColNumberEditLetter & "2:" & LColNumberEditLetter & LRowFWR)
Range(LColNumberEditLetter & "2:" & LColNumberEditLetter & LRowFWR).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    
Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
'ADJUST BUs to MATCH

'FIND
    Dim ColBUSubAfterTheFact As Long
    
    ColBUSubAfterTheFact = Cells.Find(What:="BU Subregion", _
                        After:=Range("A1"), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        
    'Convert Cell Number to Column Letters
    Dim ColBUSubAfterTheFactLetter
        ColBUSubAfterTheFactLetter = Split(Cells(1, ColBUSubAfterTheFact).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
        
    'Convert Cell Number to Column Letters
    Dim ColBUSubAfterTheFactLetter2
        ColBUSubAfterTheFactLetter2 = Split(Cells(1, ColBUSubAfterTheFact + 1).Address(True, False), "$")(0)

Columns(ColBUSubAfterTheFactLetter2 & ":" & ColBUSubAfterTheFactLetter2).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range(ColBUSubAfterTheFactLetter2 & "2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'Start Here'!C" & ColStartHereInput & ":C" & ColStartHereVariable & ",2,FALSE),""Other"")"
Range(ColBUSubAfterTheFactLetter2 & "2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ColBUSubAfterTheFactLetter2 & "2:" & ColBUSubAfterTheFactLetter2 & LRowFWR)
Range(ColBUSubAfterTheFactLetter2 & "2:" & ColBUSubAfterTheFactLetter2 & LRowFWR).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range(ColBUSubAfterTheFactLetter & "2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Columns(ColBUSubAfterTheFactLetter2 & ":" & ColBUSubAfterTheFactLetter2).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range(ColBUSubAfterTheFactLetter & "1").Select
    
Columns(LColNumberEditLetter & ":" & LColNumberEditLetter).Select
Columns(LColNumberEditLetter & ":" & LColNumberEditLetter).EntireColumn.AutoFit

Application.CutCopyMode = False


What exactly does "crash" look like?

All open windows in excel just disappear and I have to reopen the application and then when I do it shows recovered files for my review

I would start by reviewing this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?r=Saves_AllUserSaves

There's quite a bit to address there if you want to make your code more robust (and a lot shorter).
For example:

Skip the column number >> letter conversions

Dim colNum As Long, colLetter As String

colNum = 2 'for example

'don't do this...
colLetter = Split(Cells(1, ColStartHereInput).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
Range(colLetter & "2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "..."

'when you can do this...
Cells(2, colNum).FormulaR1C1 = "..." 'no Select, no number-to-letter conversion


this type of approach for replacing formulas with values:

Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

is cleaner as:
Selection.Value = Selection.Value


Use Workbook/Worksheet varaibles, and avoid implicit use of Cells/Range without a worksheet qualifier:

Dim wb As Workbook, wsStart As Worksheet

Set wb = Thisworkbook 'for example
Set wsStart = wb.Worksheets("Start Here")
ColStartHereInput = wsStart.Cells.Find(What:="Input", _
                        After:=wsStart.Range("A1"),...


Thank you for this! Tested out all points and am having no issues with 1 and 2, but when I run 3, I get Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range. I know that sheet exists in the workbook so is there something I'm doing wrong? Also this just sets the worksheet variable but it doesn't actually move you to that worksheet, right? I would still need to run a select in that case?

Thisworkbook is the workbook where the VBA is running: if that's not the same workbook which has "Start Here" then maybe you need  Set wb = ActiveWorkbook ?  Note that to do something on a sheet using VBA, you don't need to switch to that sheet, except in rare cases. You can copy/paste/delete etc without the sheet being selected/active.  Select is mainly an artifact of the macro recorder.

Thanks for the background on not needing to select. I changed to ActiveWorkbook and the error disappeared. But when I add back in ColStartHereInput = then I now get this error, "Object variable or With block variable not set". Aside from the link you pasted yesterday, do you have any recommendations on formal education or anything to help with understanding the above?

That error typically points to a case where you're trying to assign an object-type variable (eg Range/Worksheet etc) without using Set, but I assume your ColStartHereInput is declared as Long ?  For learning excel VBA, I'm a book-preferer (there was no you-tube when I learned VBA) so something like https://www.amazon.com/Excel-2019-Power-Programming-VBA/dp/1119514924/ref=sr_1_1 would be pretty comprehensive.
